# Font error in Firefox

Tags: firefox, woff

I'm getting this error in Firefox 51.0.1 conole:

`downloadable font: maxp: bad max_zones: 0 (font-family: "t" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0) source: data:application/font-woff2;base64,d09GMgABAAAAAADcAAoAAAAAAggAAACWAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABk4ALAoUNAE2AiQDCAsGAAQgBSAHIBtvAcieB3aD8wURQ+TZazbRE9HvF5vde4KCYGhiCgq/NKPF0i6UIsZynbP+Xi9Ng+XLbNlmNz/xIBBqq61FIQRJhC/+QA/08PJQJ3sK5TZFMlWzC/iK5GUN40psgqvxwBjBOg6JUSJ7ewyKE2AAaXZrfUB4v+hze37ugJ9d+DeYqiDwVgCawviwVFGnuttkLqIMGivmDg  (unknown)`

Chrome does not show this, and Safari shows several warnings that say `Unexpected CSS token: : woff.css:1:#` where `#` is a 4 digit number. There are no woff.css files in my project directory, only woff.json and woff2.json, so I don't know what to make of that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide the code to where you defined the font.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy which font are you referring to? font-family: "t"? No such font exists in my project if that is the one you are referring to.

Comment: please show the code

Comment: @Thailand there is no code to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example (2022) of the error as asked above:

```
GET https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/chakrapetch/v8/cIflMapbsEk7TDLdtEz1BwkebIl1R5_F_gUk0w.woff2
[HTTP/2 200 OK 27ms]
```

The 200 response code suggests the file is served okay (as does an inspection of the response headers).

Error is:

```
downloadable font: maxp: Bad maxZones: 0 (font-family: "Chakra Petch" style:normal weight:500 stretch:100 src index:0) source: https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/chakrapetch/v8/cIflMapbsEk7TDLdtEz1BwkebIl1R5_F_gUk0w.woff2
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31261650)